# Can D-Bus be used over streams which aren’t Unix domain sockets?

Tags: ipc, dbus

I am using DBus in a project. I understand from DBus specification that for low level communication, it uses Unix domain sockets. I don't want to use Unix domain sockets for low level communication because I have a modified `connect()` call. Is there any other type of low level communication that DBus supports which does not use `connect()`?
If yes then how to switch to that mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the [D-Bus Tutorial](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html#addresses), at the moment, D-Bus only supports sockets, which may be Unix-domain or TCP/IP.